# Exporting a database with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database

I followed some instructions over the net how to export your database. When I finished the adminitration I got this txt file:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump


SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `article`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `article` (
  `Title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Article` text NOT NULL,
  `Topics` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `page` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tpage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;






DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comments`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `comments_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comments_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Was the export successful. Is it only a textfile.. that I use to pass between computers or upload to a hosting site?

Comment: was there any data that you wanted to export? Or just the schema?

Comment: well, I emptied teh whole thing before exporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Was the export successful.

It looks like it, at least as far as the table *structure* is concerned. If the table contained data and you want that to be included, you may need to refine your command line settings. If you need suggestions on how to do that, show how you do the export.

> Is it only a textfile.. that I use to pass between computers or upload to a hosting site?

Yes, that's basically the idea of a mySQL dump - that's fine.

If it's big and you need to transport it through the web, mySQL dumps (as long as they don't contain a lot of BLOB data) compress very well, e.g. using gzip.

Comment: hmmm..thanks for the answer. I will give you an 'accept' after 2 mins